# Serialize File object for needs of redux-store

Tags: javascript, file, redux, blob

The case is - I can't send to API the files uploaded by user immediately after he drops it, because API doesn't provide such feature.

Next thing is - I want to keep my file input component reusable. I don't want to use state, I want to keep that file uploaded by user in the `redux-store`, just like the rest of fields in the form containing file input.

Has anyone encountered such situation? AFAIK, `File` object is not serializable. However, I've tried to get every prop from the `File` and save it inside javascript object **and then** store it inside `redux-store` and before sending to API, make a `File` once again with constructor (`new File(...args)`) and with the properties stored before inside store.

But still, I have failed, because as Randy Casburn stated, javascript runtime doesn't have access to some data inside that `File` object, so Im unable to copy it properly.

So once again - is there any other way to serialize `File` object so I can store it properly inside `redux-store`? Thank you for all possible comments.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @codin Yes, will post a full answer soon

Comment: Thanks, In the meantime I was able to clone the file object using lodash and preserve it in in-memory object and reuse it later for post.